# Question regarding python sorted function with two keys

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I have the following code trying to sort a list of file paths using sorted function.

```
import re
    
# Method 1
get_label = lambda x: re.search('IVsVg_([a-z])([0-9]+).dat', x).groups()
sorted(data2, key = lambda x: (get_label(x)[0], int(get_label(x)[1])))

# Method 2
sorted(data2, key = lambda x: (re.search('IVsVg_([a-z])([0-9]+).dat', x).group(1), int(re.search('IVsVg_([a-z])([0-9]+).dat', x).group(2))))
```

The first question is how does the sort function handle two keys? Because when I only use one key the list will be sorted to the following order which isn't what I wanted:

```
a1, a10, a11, a2, a3
```

But when I use two keys as in the code above the list is properly sorted to be:

```
a1, a2, a3, a10, a11
```

The second question is in the above code example. Which method is more efficient? Or are they the same? How many times is the lambda function being called for each sort in both methods? According to my friend, the first method only calls the lambda function once but the second method calls the lambda function twice. Can anyone explain why the first one only call the lambda function once? Thank you.

Comment: can you demonstrate the results you want?  what are the two keys your trying to sort on the file list?

Answer (score 3):

The second of those is slightly more efficient, but the difference is likely to be pretty marginal. Both of them do the same regex search twice per entry, which is not great. A more efficient – not to mention easier to read – way would be:

```py
def key(x):
    groups = re.search('IVsVg_([a-z])([0-9]+).dat', x).groups()
    return (groups[0], int(groups[1]))
sorted(data2, key=key)
```

Your questions about how often functions are called are a bit unclear. `sorted` calls its `key` argument once per item. In method 1, this additionally calls `get_label` twice per item, which method 2 doesn't do. As far as I can tell, your friend is talking nonsense, but this is probably just miscommunication – it seems an odd claim to make.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, sorry for the late response.